# matplotlib.pyplot, preserve aspect ratio of the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Assuming we have a polygon coordinates as polygon = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ...], the following code displays the polygon:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.fill(*zip(*polygon))
plt.show()
```

By default it is trying to adjust the aspect ratio so that the polygon (or whatever other diagram) fits inside the window, and automatically changing it so that it fits even after resizing. Which is great in many cases, except when you are trying to estimate visually if the image is distorted. How to fix the aspect ratio to be strictly 1:1?

(Not sure if "aspect ratio" is the right term here, so in case it is not - I need both X and Y axes to have 1:1 scale, so that (0, 1) on both X and Y takes an exact same amount of screen space. And I need to keep it 1:1 no matter how I resize the window.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to equalize the scales of x-axis and y-axis in Python matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990845/how-to-equalize-the-scales-of-x-axis-and-y-axis-in-python-matplotlib)

Comment: This question, asked on May 29, 2010, is a possible duplicate of a question asked on August 1, 2013, and not the other way around. It may already have an answer in the future (which is now the past). Wtf, rly...

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Does it help to use:

```
plt.axis('equal')
```

Comment: you can also use `plt.axis('scaled')`

Comment: I don't understand why, but contrary to `scaled` setting, when I changed `ylim` and `xlim` after `axis('equal')`, the tick sizes became *unequal*, and even some data from my scatter plot became cropped out...

Comment: what is the difference of using  plt.axis('scaled') and plt.axis('equal')?

Comment: By default, it seems that `plt.axis('equal')` adjusts the vertical height of the axes to achieve equal scales along X and Y. Is it possible to have matplotlib adjust the horizontal size instead?

Answer (score 38):

## 'scaled' using plt

The best thing is to use:

```
 plt.axis('scaled')
```

As  Saullo Castro said. Because with equal you can't change one axis limit without changing the other so if you want to fit all non-squared figures you will have a lot of white space.

### Equal

[image]

### Scaled

[image]

## 'equal' using ax

Alternatively, you can use the [axes class](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html).

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = figure.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(image)
ax.axes.set_aspect('equal')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I think this answer definitely deserves more upvotes.

Answer (score 19):

There is, I'm sure, a way to set this directly as part of your plot command, but I don't remember the trick.  To do it after the fact you can use the current axis and set it's aspect ratio with "set_aspect('equal')". In your example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.fill(*zip(*polygon))
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
plt.show()
```

I use this all the time and it's from the examples on the matplotlib website.

Comment: Try also `pylab.gca().set_aspect('equal', 'box')`. 'box' adjusts *both* of the axis limits (no whitespace around e.g. contourplot). 'datalim' adjusts only one of the limits (only x or y whitespace desappears). There is also 'box-forced' for exotic shared axis.

Answer (score 1):

Better `plt.axis('scaling')`, it works better if you want to modify the axes with `xlim()` and `ylim()`.

Comment: I think it was meant to say `'scaled'`. Which is already mentioned in other answers.