# How do I equalize the scales of the x-axis and y-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, aspect-ratio

How do I create a plot where the scales of `x-axis` and `y-axis` are the same?

This equal ratio should be maintained even if I change the window size. Currently, my graph scales together with the window size.

I tried:

```
plt.xlim(-3, 3)
plt.ylim(-3, 3)
plt.axis('equal')
```

Comment: for 3d, you have to do a little bit extra work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685386/matplotlib-equal-unit-length-with-equal-aspect-ratio-z-axis-is-not-equal-to

Answer (score 307, accepted):

Use [`Axes.set_aspect`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html) in the following manner:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(5))
plt.xlim(-3, 3)
plt.ylim(-3, 3)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.draw()
```

Comment: Awesome! It indeed works like charm. Could you please tell me what `plt.plot(range(5))` and `plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')` do, if you don't mind? Also, I notice that even if I don't have `plt.draw()`, the plot will still show up. Then what is the use of it?

Comment: the `plot` is just have something to show.  For the `set_aspect` read the documentation link.  The `draw` is just to make sure it gets rendered.

Comment: Sorry but I am asking about the range(5) thing inside plot(). What does the range(5) do?

Comment: ah, `range(5)` returns `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

Comment: yah, I know it returns that, but then why do I feed the list to plot()?

Comment: to have some fake data to plot (it should have plotted a straight line).

Comment: @perfectionm1ng no worries, took me a while to figure out what you were asking.

Comment: I don't see the need to set both limits to the same ranges, this can result in different scales, especially when most plots are not square shaped.

Comment: Is there a way to get this done without having to specify exactly the limits? I would have expected there to be a simple command to get a square plot with the same scale and ticks for both axis. Thanks

Comment: @Confounded: As stated below, if you don't want to give any limits you can just use `plt.axis('square')`

Comment: This is really great, thank you. For a specific subplot you can also do `ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')`

Answer (score 105):

```
plt.axis('scaled')
```

works well for me.

Comment: Also worked for me. Just make sure to use this before setting limits/ticks, as it will rescale automatically.

Comment: Sorry, plt.axis('scaled') didn't work for me in Python 3.7 and matplotlib - matplotlib==3.1.0         
However, plt.axis('square') worked!

Comment: @rishijain ValueError: Unrecognized string squared to axis; try on or off

Comment: @MonaJalal it's `plt.axis('square')` not `plt.axis('squared')`

Answer (score 73):

See [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html) on `plt.axis()`. This:

```
plt.axis('equal')
```

doesn't work because it changes the limits of the axis to make circles appear circular. What you want is:

```
plt.axis('square')
```

This creates a square plot with equal axes.

Answer (score 24):

Try something like:

```
import pylab as p
p.plot(x,y)
p.axis('equal')
p.show()
```

Comment: This works on my system, perhaps you could show a portion of the code you are working on?  Might be able to help work out the issue quicker.

Comment: This does NOT work in general. The axes are equal, but the plot is not square, unless the plotting window is also square. Tested with Matplotlib 2.0

Comment: `P.axis('equal')` seems to be like `P.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')`. While if `adjustable='box'`, then the plot becomes square.

Comment: I definitely do *not* get a square box out of this.

Comment: pylab is deprecated

Comment: If you want to also have the grid square, in addition to aspect as mentioned in the other answers, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65049909/55935

Comment: @PeterDrake: The goal isn't to get a square box, but to have the same scale in the x and y axes. So circles will be displayed as circles, but if you don't plot a square or any object with the same width as the height, you won't get a square box either.