# Define the limits of my axes, but with an equal scale in both directions

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

How do I combine those statements:

```
pyplot.axis([1234.0, 1773.0, 497.0, 1362.0])
pyplot.axis('equal')
```

I just want to define the limits of my axes, but with an equal scale in both directions.

P.S.: I tried `pyplot.axis([1234.0, 1773.0, 497.0, 1362.0], 'equal')`, but didn't worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scale still seemed not right with using

```
pyplot.axis([1234.0, 1773.0, 497.0, 1362.0], aspect = 'equal')
```

I searched a bit further on StackOverflow and changed my code to:

```
pyplot.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
pyplot.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
```

The `adjustable='box'` was necessary for a question about a 3D plot, but seems also necessary for my 2D plot.

Sources:

[2D plot question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990845/how-to-equalize-the-scales-of-x-axis-and-y-axis-in-python-matplotlib)

[3D plot question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685386/matplotlib-equal-unit-length-with-equal-aspect-ratio-z-axis-is-not-equal-to)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to define a parameter, but call the parameter list out of order and/or omit some parameters, you need to specify which parameter you are trying to set.

In this case, you want to set `aspect` so just assign `'equal'` to that.

```
pyplot.axis([1234.0, 1773.0, 497.0, 1362.0], aspect = 'equal')
```

Comment: Found out that it still is not the right scale, but I added this now: pyplot.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box') which works because I used my measuring rod.