# Easy way to change axis limits in subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, subplot

How do I change the limits on the axes in matplotlib subplots?

For example if I have

```
x = np.linspace(0,4*np.pi,100)

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(x,np.sin(x))
plt.xlim([0,4*np.pi])
plt.ylim([-1,1])
plt.axis('equal')

plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(x,np.cos(x))
plt.xlim([0,4*np.pi])
plt.ylim([-1,1])
plt.axis('equal')
```

I tried using `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim` but these didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

What you have works if you just remove the `plt.axis('equal')` lines.

EDIT: To answer your comment considering scales, this is the code that should work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   

x = np.linspace(0,4*np.pi,100)

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(x,np.sin(x))
plt.xlim([0,4*np.pi])
plt.ylim([-1,1])
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')


plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(x,np.cos(x))
plt.xlim([0,4*np.pi])
plt.ylim([-2*np.pi,2*np.pi])
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
```

[image: Output image showing proper scales]

Solution courtesy of [How to equalize the scales of x-axis and y-axis in Python matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17990845/633093)

Comment: Is there a way to set the limits on both axes and to have the scales on both axes equal at the same time?