# Axes class - set explicitly size (width/height) of axes in given units

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis, axes

I want to to create a figure using matplotlib where I can explicitly specify the size of the axes, i.e. I want to set the width and height of the axes bbox.

I have looked around all over and I cannot find a solution for this. What I typically find is how to adjust the size of the complete Figure (including ticks and labels), for example using `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(w, h))`

This is very important for me as I want to have a 1:1 scale of the axes, i.e. 1 unit in paper is equal to 1 unit in reality. For example, if xrange is 0 to 10 with major tick = 1 and x axis is 10cm, then 1 major tick = 1cm. I will save this figure as pdf to import it to a latex document.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990845/how-to-equalize-the-scales-of-x-axis-and-y-axis-in-python-matplotlib) brought up a similar topic but the answer does not solve my problem (using `plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')` code)

From this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306510/determine-matplotlib-axis-size-in-pixels) I see that it is possible to get the axes size, but not how to modify them explicitly.

Any ideas how I can set the axes box size and not just the figure size. The figure size should adapt to the axes size.

Thanks!

For those familiar with [pgfplots](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/) in latex, it will like to have something similar to the `scale only axis` option (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301594/scale-only-axis-only-for-one-axis) for example).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The axes size is determined by the figure size and the figure spacings, which can be set using [`figure.subplots_adjust()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust).  In reverse this means that you can set the axes size by setting the figure size taking into acount the figure spacings:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def set_size(w,h, ax=None):
    """ w, h: width, height in inches """
    if not ax: ax=plt.gca()
    l = ax.figure.subplotpars.left
    r = ax.figure.subplotpars.right
    t = ax.figure.subplotpars.top
    b = ax.figure.subplotpars.bottom
    figw = float(w)/(r-l)
    figh = float(h)/(t-b)
    ax.figure.set_size_inches(figw, figh)
          
fig, ax=plt.subplots()

ax.plot([1,3,2])

set_size(5,5)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help @ImportanceOfBeingErnest !!! this seems to work very well in the generated pdf (like magic!). An important note is that the `set_size` should be executed just before saving the figure in order to account for all changes in the labels and ticks. However I noticed two problems: (1) if the size of the figure is too small the labels are clipped and (2) when I print the pdf the size does not correspond to the reality scale. Why is that? Note that I call the pdf in a latex document as a figure with `\includegraphics` and then I print the generated pdf.

Comment: (1) That is to be expected. You may want to set larger spacings using `fig.subplots_adjust()`. (2) by printing you mean print to paper using an ink or laser printer? That would possibly have totally different reasons. First check if the size in the pdf itself is correct. I assume this to be the case, next check if the size in the latex is correct. This may or may not be the case. Finally the printed paper may have a different scale depending on the printer settings.

Comment: I use the pdf measure tool to check the size of the latex pdf and it is right but not on paper after printing in a laser printer.

Comment: I see. But as the latex pdf has the correct size, I think we cannot give support on printing issues on StackOverflow. Check your printer settings, look for similar issues on other pages, possibly on superuser.stackexchange or ask a question there.

Comment: Hello again @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I discovered that the function does not work when using a colorbar in the figure. How you can account for the colorbar?

Comment: You can add an axes for the colorbar (`add_axes`) and make some space for it using `subplots_adjust`.

Comment: I'm getting very different sizes for the axes using this method. Maybe it's because I have different axis limits for each of my plots? Here are the different plots, including their differing sizes https://imgur.com/a/h29DSVS

Answer (score 7):

It appears that Matplotlib has helper classes that allow you to define axes with a fixed size [Demo fixed size axes](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/demo_fixed_size_axes.html)

Answer (score 4):

I have found that ImportanceofBeingErnests answer which modifies that figure size to adjust the axes size provides inconsistent results with the paticular matplotlib settings I use to produce publication ready plots. Slight errors were present in the final figure size, and I was unable to find a way to solve the issue with his approach.  For most use cases I think this is not a problem, however the errors were noticeable when combining multiple pdf's for publication.

In lieu of developing a minimum working example to find the real issue I am having with the figure resizing approach I instead found a work around which uses the fixed axes size utilising the divider class.

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import Divider, Size
def fix_axes_size_incm(axew, axeh):
    axew = axew/2.54
    axeh = axeh/2.54

    #lets use the tight layout function to get a good padding size for our axes labels.
    fig = plt.gcf()
    ax = plt.gca()
    fig.tight_layout()
    #obtain the current ratio values for padding and fix size
    oldw, oldh = fig.get_size_inches()
    l = ax.figure.subplotpars.left
    r = ax.figure.subplotpars.right
    t = ax.figure.subplotpars.top
    b = ax.figure.subplotpars.bottom

    #work out what the new  ratio values for padding are, and the new fig size.
    neww = axew+oldw*(1-r+l)
    newh = axeh+oldh*(1-t+b)
    newr = r*oldw/neww
    newl = l*oldw/neww
    newt = t*oldh/newh
    newb = b*oldh/newh

    #right(top) padding, fixed axes size, left(bottom) pading
    hori = [Size.Scaled(newr), Size.Fixed(axew), Size.Scaled(newl)]
    vert = [Size.Scaled(newt), Size.Fixed(axeh), Size.Scaled(newb)]

    divider = Divider(fig, (0.0, 0.0, 1., 1.), hori, vert, aspect=False)
    # the width and height of the rectangle is ignored.

    ax.set_axes_locator(divider.new_locator(nx=1, ny=1))

    #we need to resize the figure now, as we have may have made our axes bigger than in.
    fig.set_size_inches(neww,newh)
```

Things worth noting:

- Once you call `set_axes_locator()` on an axis instance you break the `tight_layout()` function.
- The original figure size you choose will be irrelevent, and the final figure size is determined by the axes size you choose and the size of the labels/tick labels/outward ticks.
- This approach doesn't work with colour scale bars.
- This is my first ever stack overflow post.

Comment: My answer will not give inaccurate results. But of course you may justify your claim with an example.

Comment: Ok, after further testing I can see that with base rcParams then your code works without inaccuracy for an output pdf file (the interactive plot is wrong for at least 1x1 inch).  I doubt I'll put any more time into working out which particular parameter causes the issues as I have a solution that works for my use case, but if I were to guess it is  'text.usetex = True'.  I edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

another method using fig.add_axes was quite accurate. I have included 1 cm grid aswell

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

# This example fits a4 paper with 5mm margin printers

# figure settings
figure_width = 28.7 # cm
figure_height = 20 # cm
left_right_magrin = 1 # cm
top_bottom_margin = 1 # cm

# Don't change
left   = left_right_magrin / figure_width # Percentage from height
bottom = top_bottom_margin / figure_height # Percentage from height
width  = 1 - left*2
height = 1 - bottom*2
cm2inch = 1/2.54 # inch per cm

# specifying the width and the height of the box in inches
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(figure_width*cm2inch,figure_height*cm2inch))
ax = fig.add_axes((left, bottom, width, height))

# limits settings (important)
plt.xlim(0, figure_width * width)
plt.ylim(0, figure_height * height)

# Ticks settings
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.MultipleLocator(5))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mpl.ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.MultipleLocator(5))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(mpl.ticker.MultipleLocator(1))

# Grid settings
ax.grid(color="gray", which="both", linestyle=':', linewidth=0.5)

# your Plot (consider above limits)
ax.plot([1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,17])

# save figure ( printing png file had better resolution, pdf was lighter and better on screen)
plt.show()
fig.savefig('A4_grid_cm.png', dpi=1000)
fig.savefig('tA4_grid_cm.pdf')
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to write a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried some of this answers, but what I wanted was a better plt.subplots that let me specify the size of the axes instead of the whole figure. Turns out jupyter and pyplot are keen on resizing things, so I did my own version:

```
def subjectively_better_subplots(nrows, ncols, margin= 2, header = 2, subheight = 8, subwidth= 8): ## now it is in cm

    m = margin /2.54
    h = header /2.54

    a = subheight/2.54
    b = subwidth /2.54

    ## Here I calculate the figure size that you need for these parameters, as OP asked for. 

    width = ncols * (m + b+ m)
    height = nrows * (h +a +h)

    axarr = np.empty((nrows, ncols), dtype =object)
    
    #print(height, width)

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))

    for i in range(nrows):
        for j in range(ncols):
            axarr[i,j] = fig.add_axes([(m+j*(2*m+b))/width,
                (height - (i+1)*(2*h+a)+h)/height,
                b/width,
                a/height])

    return fig, axarr
```

It should return fig and axs just like subplots, so it can quickly replace a subplots call.